# InstallShield display uninstall user interface

Tags: user-interface, installshield, uninstallation, shortcut

I have an application that can be uninstalled via a shortcut, which executes msiexec.exe /x {ProductCode}. When I click the shortcut it launches the Execute phase of the uninstall, however, it skips the preceding phase where user interface dialogs are displayed. If I run from the MSI file directly to uninstall it displays these dialogs. I have a password that is needed from the user that is gathered in one of these dialogs, so how would I create an uninstall shortcut that displays the full user interface GUI?

Comment: I actually was able to do it by adding /qf to the command. This works for the shortcut target, but how would I add the /qf switch to the Remove button under Add\Remove Programs?

Answer (score 2):

Alas, you can't really modify the command run from the Remove button. Some options are to disable the Remove button and use the Change button, or to create a non-Windows Installer wrapper that runs a command of your choice.